# How can I save and protect sexy pictures sent by my girlfriend?

Tags: sms, security, photos, privacy, active-sync

I'm traveling and my GF wants to send me some racy pictures.  Of course I will accept that offer, but I need to save them on my phone in a safe way.

My phone uses Activesync, so [it's possible for my office to reset my pin code](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996351%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) and so I need an extra layer of protection for more intimate pictures.

She has an iPhone so I think she will send them over SMS, but I can ask her to do it a different way.  What are my options?

Comment: To start with, you should have probably used an anonymous account to ask this question. :D

Comment: My personal opinion is any pictures sent via SMS should be considered public domain. Probably be easier to upload pics to something like tumblr and check it on a frequent basis. I hear twitter works well. *goofy grin**

Comment: Let her send it to me I will protect it for you

Answer (score 4):

You should try [Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartanuj.hideitpro) from Anuj Tenani. You can also save videos, images and audio which were send via any application from the gallery.
It's also available on [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hide-it-pro/id523488488).

--About the app --

The app is cleverly disguised as "Audio Manager" in the App Drawer.
Disguises itself as a Audio Manager app which can be used to turn the volumes up and down. but if you Long press on the Audio Manager title the actual Hide It Pro app will launch, which is basically your secret vault of pics/videos/messages/apps etc.

-- Features in Detail --

1.) App disguised behind a fully functional Audio Manager

2.) Categorize media into folders of your choice

3.) Batch(Multi-Select) support for hiding and unhiding pictures

4.) Delete/Share/Unhide/Move pictures between albums

5.) Sort files by date/size/name and sort folders by count/name

6.) Gallery features Pinch to Zoom , Double tap to zoom , One finger hold and move zoom

7.) Slideshow with Fade, Zoom, Swipe effects

8.) Send/Share pictures

9.) Special optimization for low end phones.

10.) Video player features play/pause/forward/rewind/next video/prev video support

11.) Disappears from recent apps list

12.) Two lock screen options viz Pin and Password

13.) Escape pin/password for times when you get caught

14.) Built in encryption tool(with military standard 256-bit AES encryption) to secure your most important files

15.) Plugins for features like Private Messaging / Calls , Private Browsing , Locking Apps.
etc.

Answer (score 3):

If she's going to send them via SMS, you could lock your Messaging app with a 3rd-party app like [SMS Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smslocker).

Or if you want to hide/lock messages for specific contacts, try [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms)'s Private feature. You set a contact as private, and you will be asked to input a code every time you go to your Private inbox. This is separate from your usual/public inbox. Not sure if there are other types of unlocking mechanism, but I used a code which can be different from your PIN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want hide those pics then -
- use smart lite locker(app)[android]

If you're not saving them on your device then lock those apps on which your sexy GF is sending pics 
- use APPLOCK(app)[android] or else you can lock with Smartlite locker also (both are apps)[android]

[link to the APPLOCK app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en)

[link to the Smartlite locker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ukzzang.android.app.protectorlite&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Telegram and make a secret chat to share the photos. The messages and files in secret chats are encrypted end-to-end and for more security you can enable an autodestruction timeout in the conversation that destroy completely (inclusive at the server side) all the messages and files shared until the established time-lapse.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a two-year old questions, but I'd like to recommend you an APP File Expert. You can use its safebox feature to save and protect your intimate photos. I love this feature, which keeps my secret files safe and private. It requires you to draw a only-you-know patter and confirmed with your own email address.